# Laravel call static function based on var

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

Ok so I'm sure there's a nice way to do this. But I'm stuck.

Basically, I have a folder of 'custom handler's that run functions on sets of products. Folder (and namespace) structure looks like this

```
HANDLERS
-MAIN
--Generate.php
--List.php
-THREAD
--Generate.php
--List.php
-TEST
--Generate.php
--List.php
```

Inside the 'generate.php' and 'list.php' are static functions, which they all share. In my controller, I want to call one of these handlers based on an atrribute of the model. Something like:

```
\Handlers\$product->handler\Generate::go();
```

If the product used 'Thread' it would call

```
\Handlers\Thread\Generate::go();
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `call_user_func` to call a method on a dynamic class name, e.g.:

```
<?php
namespace MyPackage;

class Foo
{
    public static function bar()
    {
        echo 'Hello';
    }
}

$className = "\\MyPackage\\Foo";
call_user_func([$className, 'bar']);
```

Comment: Ahhh, could've guessed this one! I should've just tried it instead of trying to think of some unique way of handling this. Will accept in 5 mins :)